# Why is MixedGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction() taking up so much time?

Tags: mongodb, grails

I'm looking through my newrelic analysis and I'm seeing in almost every case over 60%-70% of my time is spent inside MixedGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction().  I've checked the traces and it's spent in executeAction() after the controller has already handled the action.  So it's after invokeAction() has been called, but I can't find any locks that might be holding it up.  All the time seems to be spent in executeAction().  No other methods it calls show any significant time spent in them.  I am using the MongoDB gorm plugin usually returning JSON data.

So what's the problem?

Comment: Did you find what is happening? We are seeing similar issue for our appn. New Relic shows `MixedGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction()` is taking more time.

Comment: No not exactly.  I finally came to the conclusion it was time spent actually writing things to MongoDB and writing the response to the network.  Other than that I couldn't explain it.